# Hide iFrame Scrollbar, make it the iframe scrollable from another scrollbar

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, iframe

I am making a responsive tool with an iframe. It does not display the correct width because of the scrollbar. Here's what I want to do. I want to hide the scrollbar in the iframe(it will then show the correct width), then I would like it to somehow be scrollable from a scrollbar outside of the iframe. Is this possible???

Comment: Is the iframe in the same domain?

Comment: no its not. heres the link and you will see what I am trying to accomplish. http://www.amgwebhosting.com/absolutesizer . The width is off in chrome because of the scrollbar. When I take it off, it is the right width.